# How to retrieve looped value attributes from <option> tag and pass to the onchange attribute in <select> tag

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the laravel framework and I created a drop down box and populated it with items from the database by looping.

```
<select class="form-control" id="username" name="username" onchange="handleSelect(elm)">     
                <option value="" selected>Select User</option>
                @foreach($getUsers as $list)
                <option value="{{$list->id}}" >{{$list->name}}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>
```

I want when I click an item in the drop down list, the value of the item clicked is passed in a url. Basically I want to reload the page with the item clicked to make changes to the page. A way I thought of doing it was to pass the value of the option clicked to the handleSelect() function but I don't know how to do that.

edit: the handleSelect() doesn't do anything. I'm just trying to pass what is in the selected looped value attribute to the handleSelect() function.

Comment: doesn't see your javascript code.. You can use ":selected" via javascript for selected item attribute

Comment: What does `handleSelect()` do?

Comment: You can use `GET` method for form and submit the form when the dropdown value changed.

Comment: You asked virtually the same question yesterday - I gave an answer using javascript to accomplish this

Comment: RamRaider I can't pass the value to elm because it is in a loop. Your answer yesterday didn't solve my issue. I got an error saying elm was empty

Answer (score 0):

A very basic javascript function to handle the `onchange` event that is fired whenever the user selects an option from the menu

```
function handleSelect(e){
    /* find element name and assign the value */
    location.search=[ e.target.name, e.target.value ].join('=');
}
```